# Need help to find/install up to date ATI drivers for kernel 3.5+

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ati, kernel, radeon

GPU: Radeon HD 5450
Distro: Ubuntu 12.10

Attempting to go to the AMD website and filling out the relevant information gives me [this](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English), however these drivers are incompatible with kernel 3.7 and when attempting to install them I get this error:

```
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.7.0-7-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.7.0-7-generic (x86_64)
```

I'm more than willing to provide any info that I am missing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you have a 3.7 kernel, but on the page you link to it says that it supports kernels 2.6 and on, up to 3.5. Can you use a 3.5 kernel? That is what comes default with Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal.